# Disable Column Sorting on Click using TableSorter 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

On click, I am loading in data via AJAX, loading in rows into the HTML and then sorting.

However, this process is being stopped by TableSorter sorting the column on click.

I don't want to prevent sorting of these columns, I just want to prevent sorting on clicking the TH element.

I've tried...
- return false
- stop propogation
- prevent default

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the original version of tablesorter, you'll need to set the `headers` option for each column:

```
headers: {
  0: { sorter: false },
  1: { sorter: false },
  // ...
}
```

If you're using my fork of tablesorter, you can set a "sorter-false" class name on the header ([demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html))

```
<th class="sorter-false">Title</th>
```